# plot other program's stdout directly with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot directly from other program stdout. I have found - should be applied to signal data is piped; but how to do that?

```
./DVM -l 1 -O 1 | gnuplot -p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what ./DVM will produce, but if it is emitting gnuplot commands that should work as shown.   If it is emitting only data values then you still need a source of gnuplot commands from somewhere, maybe as part of the gnuplot command, maybe from a separate file.  That may be the mechanism referred to by your previous advice "- should be applied".   For example to execute a simple gnuplot command that plots input [x,y] values:

```
yourcommand | gnuplot -p -e "plot '-' with lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have script that is generating some output that you want to use in your plot like:

```
$ ls
script.sh

$ cat script.sh 
#! /bin/bash

echo "1 1"
echo "2 3"
echo "5 5"
```

You can pass its output as a data to gnuplot with command:

```
./script.sh | gnuplot -p -e "plot '<cat' w l"
```

**Edit:** After taking a look in Ethan's answer I realised that you can use `'-'` insteal of `'<cat'`.

The output will look like:
[image: gnuplot chart]